Node JS Recursive Processing
We currently operate out of Oracle NetSuite, NetSuite has restrictions on governance processing limits for me to complete this within SuiteScripting... I am currently building an React/Express application to manage the server processing for our Sustainability/Traceability for our Lots. The problem that I am facing is I don't know how to recursively execute the build function I created and finding an endpoint to stop repeating. Everything I have done to this point, it will work, but it will get stuck looping forever.
async function NSRequestURI(authHeader, requestMethod, data) {
  //   console.log(authHeader, requestMethod, data)
  let adata = null;
  await axios
    .post(
      requestURL,
      {
        requestMethod: requestMethod,
        data: data,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `${authHeader}`,
        },
      }
    )
    .then(function (response) {
      adata = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

  return adata;
}

async function recursiveTrace(data) {
  console.log("RecursiveTrace");
  for (l = 0, d = data.lots.length; l < d; l++) {
    console.log(data.lots[l].lotNumber + " - Parent");
    for (x = 0, c = data.lots[l].buildInfo.lots.length; x < c; x++) {
      if (data.lots[l].buildInfo.lots[x].itemSource != "PHANTOM") {
        console.log(data.lots[l].buildInfo.lots[x].lotNumber + " - Child");
        var secondBuildInfo = await NSRequestURI(createAuthHeader("POST"), "getBuildByLot", {
          inventorydetail: data.lots[l].buildInfo.lots[x].inventorydetail,
          lotId: data.lots[l].buildInfo.lots[x].lotId,
        });
        for (a = 0, f = secondBuildInfo.length; a < f; a++) {
          console.log("Second Build Info");
          console.log(secondBuildInfo);

          const secondBuildLots = await NSRequestURI(createAuthHeader("POST"), "getComponentsByBuild", secondBuildInfo[a].id);
          data.lots[l].buildInfo.lots[x].buildInfo = {
            type: secondBuildInfo[a].recordType,
            id: secondBuildInfo[a].id,
            data: secondBuildInfo[a].values.trandate,
            docNumber: secondBuildInfo[a].values.tranid,
            lots: secondBuildLots,
          };

          console.log("Run Children Recursive Task")
          console.log(data.lots[l].buildInfo.lots[x].buildInfo)
        //   recursiveTrace(data.lots[l].buildInfo.lots[x].buildInfo);
        }
      }
    }

    console.log("  ");
  }

  //Transaction With Full Componets Defined
  return data;
}

exports.search = async (req, res, next) => {
  let traceJson = null;
  console.log(req.body);
  const { ifNumber } = req.body;
  //Get Netsuite Auth Signature for Login
  try {
    traceJson = await NSRequestURI(createAuthHeader("POST"), "BuildFromIF", ifNumber);

    //BuildJson is the Initial Sturcture for Recursive functions
    try {
      console.log("Build Recs");
      traceJson = await recursiveTrace(traceJson);

    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    sendRes(traceJson, 200, res);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

The Above Script will Generate this....
{
  "transaction": "121905",
  "type": "Item Fulfillment",
  "createFrom": "Sales Order #346346",
  "qty": null,
  "lots": [
    {
      "itemNumber": "Ex_CsAlpha100AssyItem",
      "lotId": "4463821",
      "lotNumber": "WO40599_050724",
      "itemSource": "INITIAL",
      "qty": "280",
      "buildInfo": {
        "type": "assemblybuild",
        "id": "19515079",
        "date": "5/7/2024",
        "docNumber": "25989",
        "lots": [
          {
            "itemId": "36836",
            "itemNumber": "Ex_SSAlphaAssyItem",
            "itemSource": "PHANTOM",
            "qty": 28800,
            "inventorydetail": "",
            "buildInfo": null
          },
          {
            "itemId": "16610",
            "itemNumber": "BC04000108",
            "itemSource": "STOCK",
            "qty": 28800,
            "inventorydetail": "12795431",
            "lotNumber": "51559",
            "lotId": "4405707",
            "buildInfo": null
          },
          {
            "itemId": "36833",
            "itemNumber": "Ex_RoastBlendGroundAlphaAssyItem",
            "itemSource": "STOCK",
            "qty": 720,
            "inventorydetail": "12795432",
            "lotNumber": "WO40596_050624",
            "lotId": "4463817",
            "buildInfo": {
              "type": "assemblybuild",
              "id": "19515072",
              "data": "5/6/2024",
              "docNumber": "25985",
              "lots": [
                {
                  "itemId": "36831",
                  "itemNumber": "Ex_CleanGreenBoliviaAssyItem",
                  "itemSource": "STOCK",
                  "qty": 1930.4,
                  "inventorydetail": "12795408",
                  "lotNumber": "WO40953_050624",
                  "lotId": "4463814",
                  "buildInfo": null
                },
                {
                  "itemId": "36830",
                  "itemNumber": "Ex_CleanGreenColumbiaAssyItem",
                  "itemSource": "STOCK",
                  "qty": 1447.8,
                  "inventorydetail": "12795409",
                  "lotNumber": "WO40594_050624",
                  "lotId": "4463815",
                  "buildInfo": null
                },
                {
                  "itemId": "36832",
                  "itemNumber": "Ex_CleanGreenRawandaAssyItem",
                  "itemSource": "STOCK",
                  "qty": 2413,
                  "inventorydetail": "12795410",
                  "lotNumber": "WO40595_050624",
                  "lotId": "4463816",
                  "buildInfo": null
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "processed": "false"
    },
    {
      "itemNumber": "Ex_CsAlpha100AssyItem",
      "lotId": "4463820",
      "lotNumber": "WO40599_050624",
      "itemSource": "INITIAL",
      "qty": "288",
      "buildInfo": {
        "type": "assemblybuild",
        "id": "19515078",
        "date": "5/6/2024",
        "docNumber": "25988",
        "lots": [
          {
            "itemId": "36836",
            "itemNumber": "Ex_SSAlphaAssyItem",
            "itemSource": "PHANTOM",
            "qty": 28800,
            "inventorydetail": "",
            "buildInfo": null
          },
          {
            "itemId": "16610",
            "itemNumber": "BC04000108",
            "itemSource": "STOCK",
            "qty": 28800,
            "inventorydetail": "12795428",
            "lotNumber": "51559",
            "lotId": "4405707",
            "buildInfo": null
          },
          {
            "itemId": "36833",
            "itemNumber": "Ex_RoastBlendGroundAlphaAssyItem",
            "itemSource": "STOCK",
            "qty": 720,
            "inventorydetail": "12795429",
            "lotNumber": "WO40596_050624",
            "lotId": "4463817",
            "buildInfo": {
              "type": "assemblybuild",
              "id": "19515072",
              "data": "5/6/2024",
              "docNumber": "25985",
              "lots": [
                {
                  "itemId": "36831",
                  "itemNumber": "Ex_CleanGreenBoliviaAssyItem",
                  "itemSource": "STOCK",
                  "qty": 1930.4,
                  "inventorydetail": "12795408",
                  "lotNumber": "WO40953_050624",
                  "lotId": "4463814",
                  "buildInfo": null
                },
                {
                  "itemId": "36830",
                  "itemNumber": "Ex_CleanGreenColumbiaAssyItem",
                  "itemSource": "STOCK",
                  "qty": 1447.8,
                  "inventorydetail": "12795409",
                  "lotNumber": "WO40594_050624",
                  "lotId": "4463815",
                  "buildInfo": null
                },
                {
                  "itemId": "36832",
                  "itemNumber": "Ex_CleanGreenRawandaAssyItem",
                  "itemSource": "STOCK",
                  "qty": 2413,
                  "inventorydetail": "12795410",
                  "lotNumber": "WO40595_050624",
                  "lotId": "4463816",
                  "buildInfo": null
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "processed": "false"
    }
  ]
}

The first part of the trace is created with a set structure, but is dynamically able to access input that has a .lots. I have the logic to build all of the results of the submitting data? The BuildInfo's that are Null will be populated on the recursive function, but this could go 3-6 more layers for each nested lots..
Im just not 100% sure how to ensure that it process all the children accurately, doesn't skip a record, and doesn't get stuck on a record..
I feel that I need to build some checks in the JSON to assist with the recursion, but I just don't know where to start at this point.
I would love any direction!

You are asking to do recursive if only buildInfo is null that might 3-6 more layer?

Correct... The first process builds to the level that you are seeing.. Now I need it to take this initial data structure and continue till it can't any more.

alright let me try

The logic above will build everything, and the data needed... I just need to loop it correctly and not hit a stuck infinite loop.
Each one of these lots are going to have buildInfo that need to repeat till it cant..

Where BuildInfo is Null the recursiveTask takes the prior build info as start data.

I don't understand what you want to achieve with data.lots[l].buildInfo.lots[x].buildInfo =, since it will potentially execute multiple times (because of the loop it is in), for the same l and x, overwriting what you previously assigned. Do you really only want to retain the last value assigned? If not, what do you want to happen?

Related to that: why does secondBuildInfo return an array as you seem to expect the corresponding property is not an array? This question should really have examples of what exactly those NSRequestURI requests return, case by case, i.e. for BuildFromIF, getBuildByLot and getComponentsByBuild separately.

You're creating globals everywhere: for (l = 0, d = data.lots.length; l < d; l++) { should be for (let l = 0. Always use const or let.
